# Save node when content with reference to it is created

Tags: rules

I have two content types - Review, and Business. Reviews have an entity reference field linking the review to the Business being reviewed. On the business page, I have fields that display the averages of the submitted reviews for different aspects of the Business. However, the average only updates itself when the node is saved. So, I need a way to automatically save the business page when a review referencing it is created. I'm assuming that the best way to go about doing this would be using Rules, but I am not sure what actions to assign to the Rules to make it tick. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought I had submitted an answer already, but apparently it didn't submit. So, here's the quick and dirty. Under `content is of type` select the type of content being saved. Next, under `fetch entity by id`, click on `switch to data selctor` under identifier. Next, enter `node:your-reference-field:nid`. Create another action, select `save entity`, and then select `entity fetched`, which was made available in the previous step.

Answer (score 1):

in rules (sorry the terminology is not exact) :

- action : node save
- condition : type = review
- select the bussiness from the review
- resave that business (you will have to force it probably)

or the same in a hook (node_api, operation save, nodetype review)

the best would probably be creating an agregated view end embedding that into your node (or attaching with a block, many possibilities)

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense (which is a definite possibility) but it seems as though you are just restating my issue with the last two bullets of the solution. The issue is that I don't know how to tell rules to save the node that is referenced, so I don't know how to select the business from the review and resave the business.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out myself. Thanks for the help anyway. I'll post up the answer once I am allowed to by the system.